# How to set padding for radio button in Android

Tags: android, radio-button, material-components-android

I am using the default radio button without any customization. I would like to add padding to the left of the button icon. I have tried padding-left, but it is only changing the space between the icon and text.

I know it can easily achieve by using the drawable left and setting the button null, but it could lose the animation and default style.

**My code**

```
              <com.google.android.material.radiobutton.MaterialRadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_bank"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_payment_method"
                android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:text="@string/bank"
                android:textColor="@color/textColorSecondary"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
```

**Current output**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap the material button in a **LinearLayout**, set your background `android:background="@drawable/bg_payment_method"` to the **LinearLayout** and give
`margin_left` to the **radioButton**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_payment_method" >
    <com.google.android.material.radiobutton.MaterialRadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb_bank"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="@string/bank"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorSecondary"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It would break radio group functionality if you won't have RadioButton as a direct child.  But it's not too complex to implement such behaviour by yourself.